# How to write individual txt files utilising multithreading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Hey all trust that you're well, I'm trying to get each thread to create separate **.txt files** and write to each txt file individually.

**Example:** process 1 opens **pri0.txt** and writes 10 names, whilst process two opens **pri1.txt** and write 10 names

**Outcome I received:** pri0.txt as well as pri1.txt were created, process 1 wrote 1 line to pri0.txt and the rest in pri1.txt and process 2 wrote to pri1.txt.

**Below is the code**

```
import time
import json
import threading
import itertools



limit = 10

def test(process):

    z = 0

    for _ in itertools.count(start=1):

        if z == limit:
            break

        z += 1

        time.sleep(1)

        with open(f'pri{i}.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(process[f'user{z}'] + '\n')

process = open('user.json',)
pro = json.load(process)
process.close()

process_count = 2

thread_list = []

for i in range(process_count):
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Account {i}', target=test, args=[process[i]])
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started')
    thread_list.append(t)

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Do you want to tell us what happened when you tried to run that code or shall we tell you?

Comment: Hey @vlad trust that you're well, it created both pri0.txt &  pri1.txt, however both treads wrote to pri1.txt.

Comment: Not with that code. You will get a TypeError when trying to construct the Thread object

Comment: May you provide more insight.

Comment: The *process* variable is a reference to _io.TextIOWrapper (which you have closed). It is not subscriptable. Therefore, your Thread constructor would cause:- TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable. And, because of that, **no** output files would have been created or appended to. I assume your JSON file has keys in the style of 'user1', 'user2' etc. I have no idea why you've introduced sleep. Why?

Comment: I would recommend running the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248255/discussion-between-don-eros-and-vlad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code writes in two different files individually.
As you can see in the output, the two threads are writing at the same time.

```
import threading

def writeToFile(fileNumber):
    with open(f'File{fileNumber}.txt', 'w') as file:
            for i in range(5):
                print(f"wroteToFile: {fileNumber}")
                file.write("hello\n")

thread_list = []

thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=writeToFile, args=[0]))
thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=writeToFile, args=[1]))

# start the threads
for index, thread in enumerate(thread_list):
    thread.start()
    print(f"ThreadNumber {index} started")

# wait until all threads are terminated
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Truly appreciated Philipp.

Comment: @Philipp How about joining the terminated threads? That's always a good idea

Comment: The main programm waits now until all threads are terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on the original code that prints all of the key/values from the input JSON. It shows how the loop counter needs to be passed to the individual threads rather than being used globally.

```
from threading import Thread
import json

NTHREADS = 5

def func(d, i):
    with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as output:
        for user, name in d.items():
            print(f'{user=}, {name=}', file=output)

with open('user.json') as j:
    users = json.load(j)

threads = []

for i in range(NTHREADS):
    (thread := Thread(target=func, args=(users, i))).start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

The assumption here is that user.json looks something like this:-

```
{
"user1": "John",
"user2": "Peter",
"user3": "Michael"
}
```

This code will produce 5 files each with identical content:-

```
user='user1', name='John'
user='user2', name='Peter'
user='user3', name='Michael'
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate Philipps contribution

**Edit:** removed the `time.sleep(1)` from the threads and added an extra argument `t = threading.Thread(name=f'Account {i}', target=test, args=[usr[i]]+[i])`

**Result:** both pri0.txt & pri1.txt were created, process 1 & process 2 wrote 10 unique values to each txt file.

**Final Code:**

```
import time
import json
import threading
import itertools



limit = 10

def test(usr, number):

    z = 0

    for _ in itertools.count(start=1):

        if z == limit:
            break

        z += 1

        time.sleep(1)

        with open(f'pri{number}.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(usr[f'user{z}'] + '\n')

us = open('followers.json',)
usr = json.load(us)
us.close()

process_count = 2

thread_list = []

for i in range(process_count):
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Account {i}', target=test, args=[usr[i]]+[i])
    t.start()
    print(t.name + ' started')
    thread_list.append(t)

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```